# Angular RxJS Subject subscription and unsubsciption

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I have a component to get an update from an API link but API call is not stopping when the component is destroyed. I am using a subject to do so and I unsubscribe from it. my api service is

```
public getupdate(){
  return this.httpClient.get(this.serverGetUpdate)
}
```

I have subscribed to this service in my component and want to get and updated every 3 seconds and I do get updates. Here is my code.

```
export class InprogressComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy{


subject=new Subject()
  constructor(private apiservice: ApiService) {
    
   }
  
  ngOnInit(): void {
    
    this.getupdate()
  }
  getupdate(){
    this.subject.subscribe(x=>{timer(0,3000).pipe(switchMapTo(this.apiservice.getupdate()),takeWhile(x=>x["data"]=="Something")).subscribe(console.log)})
    this.subject.next()
  }

  

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    //this.subject.next()
    this.subject.unsubscribe()
  }

}
```

I am new to RxJS and I do not understand why the API call doesn't stop after unsubscription. I am open to other suggestions too. Thank you

Comment: Have you run a console log on ngOnDestory to make sure it is being called? Also why are you calling .next() on destroy?

Comment: I apologize the .next() is commented out (edited now). I see the API is being call from the back end after destroy.

Comment: I meant is the ngOnDestory being called. Need to ensure the component is being destroyed. If you put console.log('destroyed') to find out.

Comment: @BrianSmith yes it gets destroyed and I get 'destroyed' on the console

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
export class InprogressComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy{

 dataSubscription: Subscription = new Subscription();

  ngOnInit(): void {

    this.getupdate()
  }
  getupdate() {
   this.dataSubscription = interval(3000).subscribe(() => {
     console.log('here');
   })
  }



  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.dataSubscription.unsubscribe()
  }

}
```

Comment: Thanks. This works for my problem. Can you explain why the Subject unsubscription is not working.

Comment: Hard to tell exactly without running it myself. But it looks as though the subject does get unsubscribed properly. However the timer that was kicked off and the downstream processes after the timer are not stopped, only the subject was.

Answer (score 2):

[Unsubscribe nulls the internal array of subscriptions in the Subject, it does not unsubscribe the subject from it's source](https://ncjamieson.com/closed-subjects/#subjects)

```
 dataSubscription: Subscription;

  getupdate(){
    this.dataSubscription = this.subject.subscribe(x=>{timer(0,3000).pipe(switchMapTo(this.apiservice.getupdate()),takeWhile(x=>x["data"]=="Something")).subscribe(console.log)})
    this.subject.next()
  }

  

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this?.dataSubscription.unsubscribe()
  }
```

But Brians answer above is a cleaner way to implement your functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
export class InprogressComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy{

 unsubscribe: Subject<void> = new Subject();

  ngOnInit(): void {

    this.getupdate()
  }
  getupdate() {
   this.apiService
      .getupdate()
      .pipe(takeUntil(this.unsubscribe))
      .subscribe(
        data => {
          // do your operation
        },
        error => {
         // error operation
        }
      );
  }



  ngOnDestroy(): void {
     this.unsubscribe.next();
    this.unsubscribe.complete();
  }

}
```